# ADB backup restoration on an older Android version

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, oneplus-one

I have made an adb backup of my OnePlus One running an unofficial [CM12 ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/development/daily-stock-unofficial-cm12-builds-t2948099) based on Android 5.0.2. Is it possible, considering the latest release of Android for the Nexus 5 is 5.0.1, to then restore this backup onto a Nexus 5 running 5.0.1?

Comment: related: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices/28315#28315)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to restore apps and data as far as they are no system apps. But be sure to fix permissions (Owner, Group and access) to what the system uses for all files (data and apps).

I already did this on my SIII LTE for an upgrade of Android 4.4.4 (CM11) to Android 5.0.1 (CM12) with no side effects (except some single apps that deleted and recreated their data for some reason).

> Also: Of course your device needs to be rooted to be able to write onto the `/data` partition.

Comment: This was the command I used on my Mac to backup:

Comment: ./adb backup -apk -shared -all -system

Comment: What will I lose if the target Nexus 5 isn't rooted?

Comment: You can't even restore anything as writing on `/data` is not allowed unless you have permission (system or higher). Therefore your device needs to be rooted.

Comment: I've restored to non-rooted devices via adb in Terminal before with no data loss, why should this be any different?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe (I just assume that) `adb` is running as a system service. Then restoring will work for you without any loss in data.

Comment: Ok, so I'm good to restore from 5.0.2 to 5.0.1 without adb telling me I can't as I'm restoring from a newer version to an older version, despite 5.0.2 not being available for the Nexus 5?

Comment: I don't know if `adb` gives out errors about that (possible I think) but a simple edit in some file should do the trick. For em: I never did backups with adb, only nandroid backups through recovery which works as well.

Comment: Any idea which file I'd have to edit and where?